# ProgramFiles64Folder property modified to C:\

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

We have created an installer with wix. It is working fine on my machine. But on one of the client's machine it get installed in C:\ drive. When I checked the log file, I found this line

> MSI (c) (24:28) [16:33:31:142]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ProgramFiles64Folder property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files\'. Its new value: 'C:\'.

Do anyone have any idea about it??

Comment: Is that happening on every other machine other than yours or just one particular machine? My first guess would be that the client changed the ProgramFiles path and MSI is just getting the correct path which happens to be root C:

Comment: Is there a way for client to change ProgramFiles64Folder path manually??

Comment: I think I've seen this happen when the install doesn't elevate, and therefore it can't write to any ProgramFiles folder (because that requires privilege) so it redirects to C:. So if your install goes to that folder it needs marking to require elevation. What's your Package InstallPrivileges setting?

Comment: InstallPrivileges have default value. We have not set it explicitly. It must be 'elevated'.

Answer (score 2):

We are able to find the solution. User was doing administrative installation of the product by using below command:

```
        msiexec -a "path-to-msi" -l*v <logfilename>
```

As a workaround, user should use the following command:

```
        msiexec -i "path-to-msi" -l*v <logfilename>
```